# Plugin pricing model SonarQube 6.7 unclear

Tags: sonarqube

In the new SonarQube version they introduced for some plugins a new [pricing model](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/) based on a maximum number LOCs. If we a have a program of 10.000 LOCs, will those LOCs be added to the grand total after each analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of lines (ncloc) taken into account is the number of the last analysis only.